# ASCII Art in Javadoc

Tags: javadoc

I'm trying to put some ascii art in my javadoc. I was trying with 'pre' tag but it didn't work for me. I stil get some messy bush ;/
Anyone have similar problem ?

Comment: "I was trying with 'pre' tag but it didn't work for me" What did you put in the `pre`, and in what way did it not work?

Comment: When I put something like this: 
'<pre>
Here goes the code from : http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Sample  
</pre>'
I'm using Eclipse to generate my javadoc files.

Comment: You can edit your question to include an exact sample of what you used. (Use the indention function wih the `{}` button for the code.)